# How to write test case to if Condition which is in UseEffect in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I am new to unit testing, I tried writing this simple test case but not able to do it.
Could some one help me to write test case for if condition in useEffect.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    
const Greet = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      //I am getting data from redux file
      const stateData = useSelector((state) => state.stateDatalist);
      const countryData = useSelector((state) => state.CountryDatalist);
      useEffect(() => {
        if (stateData.length === 0 && countryData.length === 0) {
          // calling another API data
          dispatch(getDetails());
        }
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
      );
};
    
export default Greet;
```

Comment: Actually, I want to write unit test case for that if condition inside useEffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store) to create a mock store with the mocked state. Each test case provides a different mock state to test different code branches.

E.g.

`Greet.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const getDetails = () => ({ type: 'GET_DETAIL' });

const Greet = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const stateData = useSelector((state: any) => state.stateDatalist);
  const countryData = useSelector((state: any) => state.CountryDatalist);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (stateData.length === 0 && countryData.length === 0) {
      dispatch(getDetails());
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Greet;
```

`Greet.test.tsx`:

```
import Greet from './Greet';
import createMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const mockStore = createMockStore([]);

describe('68904328', () => {
  test('should dispatch action for getting details', () => {
    const state = {
      stateDatalist: [],
      CountryDatalist: [],
    };
    const store = mockStore(state);
    mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Greet />
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([{ type: 'GET_DETAIL' }]);
  });

  test('should do nothing', () => {
    const state = {
      stateDatalist: [1],
      CountryDatalist: [1],
    };
    const store = mockStore(state);
    mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Greet />
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([]);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68904328/Greet.test.tsx (11.289 s)
  68904328
    ✓ should dispatch action for getting details (44 ms)
    ✓ should do nothing (4 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 Greet.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.109 s
```

package version:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, Here I am using redux toolkit, so I am not able to get the action Type to check. 
what and all response I am getting, I am storing in a slice named as "dataSlice", by setting data using dispatch(setIncomingData(response)).